# jQuery dropdown choice rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, overwrite, dropdown

Not sure if you'll get what I want, because Fiddle can't (or I don't know how) mimic the behavior of the web app. I have a dropdown HTML forms in the table. When I send the choice with AJAX, then PHP returns the name of the food (for *1.* it should return *tuna*, for *2.* it should return *ham*, etc...). I'd like the name to be presented immediately but....

```
$('td.editable').click(function () {
//$(this).off("click");
 var form = '<select id="choice" onChange="doSomething(this.value)">\
                        <option disabled selected></option>\
                        <option value="1">1</option>\
                        <option value="2">2</option>\
                        <option value="3">3</option>\
                    </select>';

 $(this).html(form);
 });
```

1. When I comment out the second line of JS, then the dropdown menu keeps hiding, and if you want to make a choice you have to hold LMB all the way through process. But, when the response comes from AJAX, it's being inserted into the cell, and if you decided it's not right choice for you, you can change your mind. This last thing I want.
2. When I leave the second line of JS, then the dropdown behaves normally, AJAX gets name of the food from PHP, and it writes it down in the cell. Problem is that dropdown menu becomes dysfunctional. That `<td>` cell doesn't react to the click anymore, and it you decide you want to change your mind, you have to reload the page to make it clickable again. How do I solve this poor UI?

Here is PHP call scheme, just for reference...

```
function doSomething(val){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "choice.php",
        data: { choice: val },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
            $("td.editable").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

And the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y64k2Lor/

Comment: In your fiddle I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined` do you have a function to go with `onChange="doSomething(this.value)"` in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, it calls PHP file which does the job, and returns a string. The 'response' variable is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having to turn on and off the click-event handler, you could use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) when registering the handler, and instead add and remove the "editable" class. With event delegation, you register the handler on the table element, but the callback is called only when a cell with the "editable" class is clicked.

You would remove the "editable" class when you display the drop-down, and then re-add it when the ajax call returns.

```
$('table').on('click', 'td.editable', function () {
    var $cell = $(this);
    var $select = $('<select>'
                   + '<option disabled selected></option>'
                   + '<option value="1">1</option>'
                   + '<option value="2">2</option>'
                   + '<option value="3">3</option>'
                   + '</select>');

    $cell.html($select).removeClass('editable');

    $select.change(function() {
        // Make ajax call here and re-add "editable" when it returns.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "choice.php",
            data: { choice: $(this).val() },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                $cell.html(response).addClass('editable');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33L1bgh8/)

Comment: Yes! I was having doubts if I'll be able to explain correctly, but this Fiddle is exactly the behavior that I want. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Dead tired by now...

Comment: Yep, did it. Thank you.